# Components rendered from state array do not update received props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic, state, react-props

I'm rendering child components from the parent's state. Their rendering is being triggered by:

```
{this.state.notificationStack}
```

The child components are being created by

```
this.state.notificationStack.push(
            <Alert alertID={'alert_' + this.state.notificationStack.length + '_' + dateTime} 
                type={type} title={title} message={message} 
                pixelstoMove={this.state.valueToUpdate} 
                key={this.state.notificationStack.length + '_' + dateTime} 
                 destroyAlertFromNotificationStack={this.destroyAlertFromNotificationStack}/>
        )
```

However I'm managing the state correctly and able to see the state changes in the parent compontent, I do not receive the updated props in the Alert component.

Comment: you need to use `setState()` to update a component state

Comment: I'm using set state on this.state.valueToUpdate.
However, Alert components are not getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like:

```
const aux = this.state.notificationStack;
aux.push(...)
this.setState({
  notificationStack: aux
});
```

So it will update the state. Simple pushing to it will **not** trigger a re-render and update child components.

Comment: That was my first approach.
However, that will force all the child components to re-render.
The problem here is that the child components behaviour will change regarding their own state.

For getting your solution to work, I would need to create a very complex handler for the behaviour of the child component. I was trying to avoid that.

Comment: you can call `this.forceUpdate()`, https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#forceupdate

Comment: I'm already doing that, otherwise I could not see the changes on the _notificationStack_ array on the DOM. However, the _valueToUpdate_ is not being updated on the child components.

Comment: I was able to solve it by updating the full array.
React is updating the current _Alerts_ receiving new props and updating current childs.
I remade my code so it was probably an error in my first approach.

Thanks guys.